# Symfony Doctrine fixtures - do not purge all tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixtures

Is there any way to prevent purging one table when using Symfony Fixtures Bundle?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late however [I created a PR](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/pull/289) that allows the use of a `--exclude-table` option. If/Once it has been merged you can use the following syntax:

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --exclude-table=table_name --exclude-table=table_2_name
```

which will run the fixtures as normal but won't purge `table_name` or `table_2_name`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do the purging in a controller, you can write code like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
...

$excludedTables = ['my_table1', 'my_table42'];

$purger = new ORMPurger($this->getDoctrine()->getManager(), $excludedTables);

$purger->purge();
```

If you want do the purging in some class that does not have access to entity manager, you'll have to inject it in the constructor of the class, or as a parameter of the purging method. A rest of the code should look similar like before, only construction of the purger should look like this:

```
$purger = new ORMPurger($injectedEntityManager, $excluded);
```

Comment: If we want to do this in `doctrine:fixtures:load` what we should do?

Comment: @YahyaE : run  `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append` but it doesn't purge… only append !

Comment: @bcag2 `--append` will not purge the tables I want to keep. But it also will not purge the tables that I want to purge.. :(